# Measuring in qiskit collapses onto the Z-Plane. Why do any rotations other than Y matter?

Tags: qiskit, measurement, quantum-circuit

We have the situation where a 50/50 split between $|1\rangle$ and $|0\rangle$. This was done using a $H$-Gate. Now, when measuring in `qiskit`, if my understanding is *correct*, we collapse onto the *Z-plane* which then results in either a *0* or a *1*.

So my question now would be, what's the practical usage of any rotation that isn't a *Y*-Rotation? As far as I can see, the *Y*-Rotation changes the amplitudes/probabilities of the measurement, where as a *Z*-Rotation does not.

Comment: A $Z$ rotation affects the phase of the state, which can be useful to get constructive/destructive interference later on.

Comment: Does that have any implications on quantum circuits? From my understanding it allows us to use even more of the complete state-space, but that isn't _per se_ directly measurable, and there for, usable to construct algorithms with.

Comment: Yes it has. Take for example the quantum Fourier transform, it uses the controlled Phase gate, which is a controlled rotation around the Z axis (in Qiskit’s implementation, it differs from the normal CRZ by a relative phase)